# Проблема с созданием словаря

Tags: python

Небоходимо сформировать объект класса dict, где ключ - это IP адрес, а значение - количество раз, которые этот ip встретился в тесте.

В итоге должно получиться что-то типа такого:

{'192.168.101.4': 1, '192.168.102.3': 2, '192.168.7.46': 1}

Comment: И в чем, собственно, проблема?

Comment: Я это вижу примерно так, только не совсем могу понять как правильнее написать условие. 
file_path = '../data/uwsgi.log'
ip_counter = dict()
with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    for row in f:
        ## ?????
        pass
print(ip_counter)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Допустим ip_list - это список с ip

```
result = {ip: ip_list.count(ip) for ip in set(ip_list)}
```